# How to call a remote API repeatedly and synchronously in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a list of emails and want more information about the users of the emails. So I call a remote API repeatedly for each email. The problem I am facing is that since the `http` module is async in NodeJS, I am not able to capture this information before the control goes elsewhere.

This is my remote API call

```
var callApi = function(email) {
    var request = http.get(apiUrl + '"' + email + '"', function (response) { 
        var buffer = '', jsonData;

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            buffer += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function (err) {
            jsonData = JSON.parse(buffer);
            jsonData = jsonData[0];
            userData[email].username = jsonData.name;
            userData[email].org = jsonData['org-title'];

            console.log(userData[email].username + ": " + userData[email].org);
        }); 
    });
};
```

I call this function in the following way

```
for(var email in userData) {
    callFaceApi(email);
}
storeDataJson(filePath, userData);
```

`storeDataJson` is being called before the requests return and the file I write to is always empty.

Comment: The short answer is that's not how `node.js` works. You either need to nest the callbacks or use `promises` (or `observables`).

Comment: *"How to call a remote API repeatedly and synchronously"* Don't, code it asynchronously instead. Either send the requests in series, or, send them in parallel and wait until they are all finished to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla javascript you could create a "queue" of emails like this:

```
var queue = [];
for (var email in userData)
    queue.push(email);
dequeue();

var dequeue = function() {
    if (!queue.length)
        return storeDataJson(filePath, userData);

    var email = queue.shift();
    callApi(email, dequeue);
}

var callApi = function(email, callback) {
    ...
    response.on('end', function (err) {
        ...
        callback();
    });
}
```

Or you could use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#) module that has lot of functionalities for this kind of tasks (e.g. `parallel` or `series`)

Comment: That did the trick! I tried async initially, but both `series` and `waterfall` did not work as expected. Maybe I didn't use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your response for each individual call is handled here:

```
response.on('end', function (err) {
```

So it is up to you to do some counting in there.

You should handle the call to

```
storeDataJson(filePath, userData);
```

in that function too, with some additional logic.

You will need to add some logic that checks if they have all been handled, and only run the function when the last one is in.

Maybe this is easier: create a function named emailDataArrived, and call that one when the response ends.
Place emailDataArrived in a place where it can access userData, and just use a counter to count the number of answers. WHen it matches the length of userData, write your file.